# Bind a function to all text input - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to bind a function to all the textarea and want to run it whenever a key gets pressed.

```
function fx(docid)
{
  $('#'+docid).val=encodeURIComponent($('#'+docid).val());
  //document.getElementByID('docid').value = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementByID('docid').value);
}
```

Note: the page will have different textarea, I want a single function to do the same job for all the textarea. I don't want to hard code the event with the textarea `<textarea onkeydown="..." />`

`Edit`
I want to trigger the function on multiple events, thats on keypress, keydown,click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in `textarea` as the selector.  If you want it to trigger for text inputs as well then use `textarea, input[type="text"]` for the selector:

```
var fxHandler = function (e) {
    var yourDocId;
    // code to find/set yourDocId
    fx( yourDocId );
};

// bind to whatever events you need
$('textarea').bind('keydown', fxHandler)
             .bind('keyup', fxHandler)
             .bind('click', fxHandler);
```

Of course, if you run your function as written it will double, triply, etc encode the value, so you'll need to write a function that leaves %## values alone.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @mVChr's answer,

```
$('textarea').bind('keypress keydown click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val(encodeURIComponent($this.val()));
});
```

but you almost certainly don't want to run the exact same function on `keypress` *and* on `keydown`.